# Array of Ofstream in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, ofstream

I want 41 output files to use in my project to write text on them. first create a string array `list` to name those output files then I tried to define an array of ofstream objects and use `list` to name them, but I get this error that `'outfile' cannot be used as a function`. Below is my code:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std ;
int main ()
{
  string list [41];
  int i=1;
  ofstream *outFile = new ofstream [41];

  for (i=1;i<=41 ;i++)
  {
    stringstream sstm;
    sstm << "subnode" << i;
    list[i] = sstm.str();
  }

  for (i=0;i<=41;i++)
    outFile[i] (list[i].c_str());

  i=1;
  for (i=1;i<=41;i++)
    cout << list[i] << endl;

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: First minor problem: you should not use list which is a reserved word std::list is a famous container. Second you need to call open(string("somefilename_or_path")) on each of the outFile members with say for (int i=0; i<outFile.szie(); ++i) { outFile[i].open(list_filename[i]); }, where list_filename[41] is your file names that should be initialized with proper values.

Answer (score 7):

See below for the following fixes:

1. don't use `new` unless you have to (you were leaking all files and not properly destructing them will lead to lost data; ofstreams might not be flushed if you don't close them properly, and the pending output buffer will be lost)
2. Use proper array indexing (starting from 0!)
3. Call `.open(...)` on a *default-constructed* `ofstream` to open a file
4. Recommendations:

   - I'd recommend against `using namespace std;` (not changed below)
   - I recommend reusing the `stringstream`. This is is good practice
   - Prefer to use C++-style loop index variables (`for (int i = ....`). This prevents surprises from `i` having excess scope.
   - In fact, get with the times and use ranged for

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    ofstream outFile[41];

    stringstream sstm;
    for (int i=0;i<41 ;i++)
    {
        sstm.str("");
        sstm << "subnode" << i;
        outFile[i].open(sstm.str());
    }

    for (auto& o:outFile)
        cout << std::boolalpha << o.good() << endl;
}
```

Comment: some"times" word "thankyou" can not express the true feeling of a person . this time is one of those "times"!!!

Comment: outFile[i].open(sstm.str()); should be outFile[i].open(sstm.str().c_str());

Comment: @abhi not if you use c++11

Comment: You can use _countof(outFile) instead of 41 in loops. At least with MSVC.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat why not just use `for (auto& o:outFile) cout << o.good() << "\n";` altogether. It's 2016

Comment: Yeah, in second loop it's even better, agree.But there is 41 in first loop too. BTW, one more compactification: `sstm.str("subnode");`

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat you do realize this is 4-year old code that I copied from the OP, right :)  Your compactification misses exactly why the `i` loop var is needed. I'm not going to turd polish this as if it were important code :)

Comment: I understand it's 4-year old post but it's still found via search engines and serves as a tutorial for someone :) So IMHO it make sense not to learn beginners to use linked constants in several places.
The rest (`sstm.str("subnode"); sstm << i;`) is cosmetics, agree. It was just side note. And I do not miss why `i` is needed. Probably I was too brief :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not call the constructor as you do. Try calling `outFile[i].open(list[i].c_str())`. Note the 'open'.

Comment: I am sorry but I could not understand what you meant with your comment

Comment: dear izomorphius your right . I just got error by compiling sehe's codein that line.

Comment: @sehe but outfile is a dynamic array of ofstreams. So outfile[i] is actually an ofstream, not a pointer to such. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Derp. I was wrong. Of course, the array doesn't store pointers. Oops. Sorry for the confusion. (@vahidzolf note tha my answer still solves the critical issues due to using `new` and I tested my solution there)