# Array of fstream in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I'm writing an algorithm with NTL library(it's a C++ library). Now I have N files to edit and I have to create/open them at the same time. I try to dynamically allocate space for the N file pointers but there's something wrong with the code. The code snippet is shown below:

```
P1 = (char **)calloc(n+1, sizeof(char *));//P1 is used to save file names
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    P1[i]=(char *)calloc(20, sizeof(char ));
    sprintf(P1[i],"P1_%d.txt",i);
}
ifstream *fin = (ifstream *)calloc(n+1, sizeof(ifstream));
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    fin[i].open(P[i]);
}
```

When the program runs in linux, it tells me there is a Segmentation Fault.

Since N is not larger than 200, when I try to use

```
ifstream fin[200]
```

instead of

```
ifstream *fin = (ifstream *)calloc(n+1, sizeof(ifstream));
```

the program runs.

I just learned C but not C++, and I don't really know how the `fstream` class works. Could you tell me if there is some better ways to open N files at the same time?

Comment: `C` does not have `ifstream`, AFAIR.

Comment: malloc/calloc functions is used in C, but not C++, you should use new instead

Comment: Arrays in C and C++ start at 0, not 1, so your loops should read `for(i=0; i<n; i++)`

Comment: @ShellCode: Please don't advise `new`. Use `std::string`.

Comment: And why I should't advise new ? If you want to alloc some memory in the heap, the right way to do so in c++ is using new

Comment: @ShellCode [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835406/array-of-ofstream-in-c) Somebody have some problem when use `new`

Answer (score 5):

`calloc` will just alloc memory, but `ifstream` is complex type. It has constructor, that should be called on object creation. I think you should read some docs/book about C++. You should allocate memory in C++ using [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). Btw, it's better to use smart pointers (such as [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)) if you use modern C++ compiler. Also, it's much better to use [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), when you want to store unknown on compile-time count of objects. In this case it will be simpler to just use `vector<ifstream>`.

```
// includes for vector and unique_ptr.
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

vector<ifstream> streams;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
   streams.push_back(ifstream(P[i]));
}
```

Comment: is it better to use vector<ifstream>?